# Axios in React doesn't show all headers of response

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I am doing a post call to the Api,

```
axios
      .post(authUrl+'/user/login', body)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("axios header response",response.headers);
       return(response);
      })
```

I get this message in console

```
axios header response { "content-length": "1129", "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
```

When I go on the Network tab on Inspect Menu, I get all the headers of the response.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    *
Connection
    keep-alive
Content-Length
    1129
Content-Type
    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date
    Tue, 22 Nov 2022 06:18:49 GMT
ETag
    W/"469-zAeRmNfvDmioaHmzPG+XynZaSYo"
Keep-Alive
    timeout=5
x-access-token
    eyJhbG......
X-Powered-By
    Express
x-refresh-token
    eyJhb......
```

How can I get all of this data on React?

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing a Cross Origin request (e.g. when your React App is served from another origin than your `authUrl`, you should also consider setting the header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` on your server.

There are only 4 headers which are considered as safe when performing a cross origin request:

- Accept
- Accept-Language
- Content-Language
- Content-Type

(see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_request_header). All other headers have to be listed in header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Under which circumstances this is necessary is explained pretty good in this link:

> The Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header is used in response to a preflight request which includes the Access-Control-Request-Headers to indicate which HTTP headers can be used during the actual request.
> This header is required if the request has an Access-Control-Request-Headers header.

Answer (score -1):

Just parse your response first

```
axios
.post(authUrl+'/user/login', data)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
 console.log(response.headers.get("x-token"));
})
```